# How to sort String ArrayList divided by separator

Tags: flutter, dart

How to sort String ArrayList divided by "," separator?

In arraylist, string is dataType, and each index is stored as below.

```
someList[0] = "abc,xxx,1"
someList[1] = "abc,xxx,3"
someList[2] = "abc,xxx,2"
someList[3] = "abc,xxx,5"
someList[4] = "abc,xxx,4"
```

The problem is I want to split and rearrange based on the last number(1,3,2,5,4 -> 1,2,3,4,5). How could I achieve this? I would really appreciate for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
someList.sort((a, b)=>a.split(',').last.compareTo(b.split(',').last));
```

Comment: wow.....you are so good how do you study usually? I haven't been able to solve it for 4 hours. Just one more question for my study purpose, if I wanted to change it to the xxx shown above, not last, how do I write it?

Comment: instead of `last`, you can refer to that 'xxx', in this case you can do like this: `a.split(',')[1]`.

Comment: For your other question, I didn't solve it from my knowledge. I googled and read [docs](https://api.dart.dev/be/137051/dart-core/List/sort.html). Then answered your question. You have to improve your google search skills